# Get multiple results using LIKE

Tags: php, sql

Say I have some records in my database with data like so:

> John Murdoch
>   I am John Murdoch
>   My first name is john and my second name is murdoch

I have a search form and I type in "john murdoch" which will run this query:

```
$search //contain the search string in this case is john murdoch
$sql = mysqli_query($sql, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%$search%'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
echo $row['first']."<br>";
}
```

This will return the first two rows only because it is only those rows that have the both words beside each other. How can I return the other row even though the words are split up? I know I could explode the string and check each piece, but I was looking for a more stable and efficient way of doing this.

Answer (score 3):

Just replace punctuation and spaces with the wildcard `%` before your query.

`$search = str_replace ( array( '.', ' ', "'", '-' ), '%', $search );`

This does still require the first word to appear in the text before the second word. So if your search was for "Murdoch John", you would not return any results.

The better answer is to employ FULLTEXT searching on the column (must do this in MySQL), and do a `MATCH()` query against the column, like so:

Add a plus sign before each word (to indicate that word is required)

`$words = '+' . str_replace( ' ', ' +', $search );`

And your query:

`SELECT * FROM table MATCH ( column ) AGAINST ( '$words' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`

More info here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Comment: I am using mysql, i just added the mysqli so people don't go off topic and tell me too stop using the mysql functions, using the FULLTEXT gives me Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Comment: @Ashley Bowman Try adding this after your `$sql = ` line: `if($sql === false) echo mysqli_error()` or whatever the mysqli error function is. You probably have sent faulty SQL, resulting in `$sql` being set to `false`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `column` LIKE '%john%' AND `column` LIKE '%murdoch%'
```

I would construct that query like this:

```
$search_terms = array('john','murdoch');
$field_to_search = 'some_column';

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE' . "\n";

$sql .= '`' . $field_to_search . '` LIKE \'%' 
   . implode('%\' AND `' . $field_to_search . '` LIKE \'%',$search_terms)
   . '%\'';
```

That PHP can be used with any number of search terms. It requires matches for all because it's connected with `AND`.

Here's a link to a php fiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/igv-3qc